# VBA INDEX MATCH LOOP

Tags: excel, vba, loops, indexing

How do I loop my index match function in VBA?

Currently my index match works fine - I now need this to loop through all the rows in "Table2" and find the matching values in "table1"

The amount of populated rows for table 1 , "N" & "I" will change every time I run a query built into my workbook. I keep getting syntax errors when running for and while loops (I am fairly new to VBA)

Please help!

Thanks,

```
total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("table1").Range("I16:I100"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Table2") _
.Range("B2"), Sheets("table1").Range("N16:N100"), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

'initialize the Range object rng with Range("A1:A10")
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
'Or if you prefer:
Set rng = Selection

'Add the For Each Next loop.
For Each cell In rng

'Do stuff

Next cell
```